# Add link to div box in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm newish to Wordpress and I tried to follow any advice on support theme forum and google but I'm stuck and I will appreciate any help.

Here's my website http://www.propit.pl 
it uses theme Lawyeria Lite and I created a child theme.

I would like to make the box around the contact to make "clickable" as it is in this website http://spectogroup.com/ which uses the same theme.

How do I do it? Add CSS to child theme? Some HTML?

Thanks for help!

Comment: clickable to who, a link, or just you like to change mouse pointer icon

Comment: then use an anchor tag, not div tag. `<a class="your-class" href="your link">contact</a>` then add style rules to `style.css` file of your active theme

Comment: /*
   Theme Name: Lawyeria Lite Child
   Theme URI: https://themeisle.com/themes/lawyeria-lite/
   Description: This is a custom child theme I have created.
   Author: Chuck Norris Author
   URI: https://www.themeisle.com/ 
   Template: lawyeria-lite
   Version: 0.1 
   */

<a class="features-box" href="http://www.google.pl">Kontakt</a> That's how the style css file looks now but it doesn't work

Comment: Dear @Alto, you are doing it all wrong, the anchor tag will go to your page/post content, not in the style.css file.

Comment: only the style rules (if any) will go to the style.css file

Answer (score 0):

Add following line to your page/post:

```
 <a class="features-box" href="google.pl">Kontakt</a>;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your boxes over there are unlinked. 
You need to wrap each box with an anchor tag in order to work

Fox ex

```
<a href="http://example.com">
   <div class="features-box">
    //Content here
    </div>
</a>
```

These will make that specified box clickable to an your desired href link

Comment: No, I meant the three boxes below ("Kontakt" "Oferta" "Promocje"). I want to make them (the boxes around) a link.